Name of property for poset
Let $(S,\leq)$ be a poset. $x\in S$ is called maximal if whenever there is $y\in S$ such that $y\geq x$, it must be $x=y$. Assume that S satisfies the following property.
For every $x\in S$, there exists $y\in S$ such that $y$ is maximal and $y\geq x$.
In words, every element in the poset is majorised by at least one maximal element.
Is there a specific name for this property and this kind of posets?
In practice, this property is equivalent to the requirement that the set of all maximal elements of $S$ is cofinal.

Zorn posets maybe?

@Trebor is this used? I've tried to google it and could not find it... do you have a ref?

If $S$ is noetherian (also called "ascending chain condition"), then it fulfills this property (but not vice versa). So, perhaps, "weakly noetherian", would be a reasonable name? But this is certainly not an established one!
